# How can I route using controller without adding the id in the url?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The url right now is `website.com/profile/1/edit` but I wanted to just only show `website.com/profile`

I have tried using the route web.php
`Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController');` and `Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@edit');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create some route like that :

```
Route::get('my_profile','ProfileController@myProfile');
```

And the function like that :

```
public function myProfile (){
    $user = Auth::User();
    if($user){
     /*
     Your code and redirect
    */
    }
    else{
    return back();
    }

}
```

Don't forget this : `use Auth;` in above of file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit profile of user who is logged in. Try getting the ID from session rather than sending it from the URL. Instead of this, you can also use post request to hide the id from URL.